# How to fix error while installing dlib on python 3.7.3 64 bit windows 10

Tags: python, cmake, dlib

I'm trying to install dlib on Windows 10 using anaconda prompt. Using pip install dlib
But I'm getting this error

```
Failed building wheel for dlib
Running setup.py clean for dlib
Failed to build dlib
```

```
    CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
      Generator

        NMake Makefiles

      does not support platform specification, but platform

        x64

      was specified.


    CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
    CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I have already installed cmake using pip install cmake and it was successfully downloaded.

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use `python3.7`? Getting the compilation set up right can be a pain, but if you switch to an environment with `python3.6` you could install using a pre built `whl` file

Comment: but is there not any way to install it in 3.7 version?

Comment: I missed the fact that you are using anaconda already. In that case an installation using `conda` might also be an option

Comment: check and try this answer from this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58570219/problem-in-installing-dlib-module-for-anaconda-on-mac-os/58624181#58624181

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, your `cmake` seems to be using a different generator than is supported for your platform. In your `cmd`, type `cmake --help`. This will print a list of generators to choose from, mine looks something like this:

```
The following generators are available on this platform:
  Visual Studio 15 2017 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2017 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 14 2015 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2015 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 12 2013 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2013 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 11 2012 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2012 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 10 2010 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2010 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "IA64".
  Visual Studio 9 2008 [arch]  = Generates Visual Studio 2008 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "IA64".
```

Make sure that you also have the `Visual Studio 15 ...` line. Then you should be able to run your installation:

1. Grab the source code, e.g. [v19.17](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/archive/v19.17.zip)
2. Unzip, and open a `cmd` in the unzipped source folder
3. run `python setup.py -G Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64`

This should tell `cmake` to use the correct visual studio generator.

Also worth mentioning, since you seem to be using anaconda, is the fact that `dlib` should be available from the `conda-forge` and can be installed like thie:

```
conda install -c conda-forge dlib
```

Comment: error: invalid command 'Studio', if the whole text given in quotes, error: no commands supplied

Comment: python setup.py **install** -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"