# unable to install dlib in vs code it shows some installation error

Tags: python

i have used every solution that i can find in the internet but i am unable to install dlib in vs code please help me

```
pip install dlib --user
Collecting dlib
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/63/92/05c3b98636661cb80d190a5a777dd94effcc14c0f6893222e5ca81e74fbc/dlib-19.19.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: dlib
  Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\program files\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\abhigna reddy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-b3pu5qni\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\abhigna reddy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-b3pu5qni\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\abhigna reddy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-dpfk1_ko\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=
         cwd: C:\Users\abhigna reddy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b3pu5qni\dlib\
    Complete output (57 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    Building extension for Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 23:03:10) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
    Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\abhigna reddy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b3pu5qni\dlib\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\abhigna reddy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b3pu5qni\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.8 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\program files\python38\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\abhigna reddy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b3pu5qni\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.8 -A x64'
    -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
      Generator

        NMake Makefiles

      does not support platform specification, but platform

        x64

      was specified.


    CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
    CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "C:/Users/abhigna reddy/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-b3pu5qni/dlib/build/temp.win-amd64-3.8/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".      
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\abhigna reddy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b3pu5qni\dlib\setup.py", line 223, in <module>
        setup(
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\abhigna reddy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b3pu5qni\dlib\setup.py", line 135, in run
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Users\abhigna reddy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b3pu5qni\dlib\setup.py", line 172, in build_extension
        subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\abhigna reddy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-b3pu5qni\\dlib\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\abhigna reddy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-b3pu5qni\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.8', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\program files\\python38\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\abhigna reddy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-b3pu5qni\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.8', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\program files\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\abhigna reddy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-b3pu5qni\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\abhigna reddy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-b3pu5qni\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\abhigna reddy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-dpfk1_ko\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix= Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix error while installing dlib on python 3.7.3 64 bit windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57588118/how-to-fix-error-while-installing-dlib-on-python-3-7-3-64-bit-windows-10)

Answer (score 0):

you can install dlib for python 3.6

create a virtual environment for python 3.6 
within virutualenv you can run below command

```
python -m pip install https://pypi.python.org/packages/da/06/bd3e241c4eb0a662914b3b4875fc52dd176a9db0d4a2c915ac2ad8800e9e/dlib-19.7.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl#md5=b7330a5b2d46420343fbed5df69e6a3f
```